# PHP, how can I check if the query runs successfully else redirect to other page with out showing error

Tags: php, mysql

this is the create function as i have added the database class.

```
id------int 
name----var
fname---var       
phone---number
```

i will run here the query which is not valid the (phone) value should be number so i will insert text to have wrong query.

```
public function create(){
$sql = "Insert into tbl_one (name,fname,phone) values('nameN','nameF',error)";
if($database->query($sql)){
 $this->id = $database->insert_id();
} else {
redirect_to('index.php');
}
```

now here how i can make if the query is false it should redirect me to one page, 
currently it will show the mysql_error and will give detail why it's wrong but i dont want
it i want it just check the query if false redirect me to other page.
do i need another function or that where i should get the hint to move on

Comment: haha, thanks, i got it back

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace error with 0

```
public function create(){
$sql = "Insert into tbl_one (name,fname,phone) values('nameN','nameF',0)";
if($database->query($sql)){
 $this->id = $database->insert_id();
} else {
redirect_to('index.php');
}
```

Comment: Dear tortune, i know it, but i want if the user insert wrong query how i can check if their query is not valid just redirect them to other page, i need a mysql_query_checking function how i can do it

Comment: @abas_rafiq : define `valid`...`valid` as in correct query with non-desired values or incorrect query - syntax error type?

Comment: yes, here i want to insert (not correct) query or bad query so if the query is bad it should redirect me to a page

Comment: whats wrong with...`$database->query($sql)`, this would be false if query is `incorrect`, so you would have `redirect` executed!!

Answer (score 0):

use exception handling

```
try {

    $sql = "Insert into tbl_one (name,fname,phone) values('nameN','nameF',error)";
    $database->query($sql);
    $this->id = $database->insert_id();

}catch(Exception $e){
    //log exception...$e

    redirect_to('index.php');
}
```

Comment: same result, as i insert (in valid query or wrong) it's shows the error it does not check and redirect to other page.